# A puzzle of words

Tags: knowledge, visual

**What is the 3-word phrase I'm looking for?**

---

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think the phrase is:

> **parts of speech**.

Each circle ...

> ... represents one major type of word. When the name of one type A is contained in another type B, the circle for A is drawn insode the circle for B. So we have: **Verbs** inside **Adverbs**, **Adjectives**, **Conjunctions** or connectives, **Nouns** inside **Pronouns**, **Determiners** (articles, prossessives, etc.), **Interjections** and **Prepositions**.
>
>  The containment is strictly by strings of letters, not semantic: "verb" is a substring of "adverb", but verbs are not a subclass or a subtype of adverbs.

The title ...

> ... speaks for itself, I think.

Comment: I think you're spot on with the findings but that the 3 words may actually be rot13([cnegf bs fcrrpu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Part_of_speech))...

Comment: Well done! And yes, as @Stiv points out, that's the phrase I was looking for.

Comment: Oh, yes, that sounds better, familiar even. But the phrase didn't occur to me, so I used a literal translation from German, which usually isn't a good idea. (At least that odd wording served me as search-engine fodder to find out about that pesky "I".)